# i need to find the upper bound of this: or the tight bound:

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, discrete-mathematics, polynomial-math

lets say i have an expression:

```
(n)+((n-1)*2)+((n-2)*3)+((n-3)*4)+...+(3*(n-2))+(2*(n-1))+(1*(n))
```

what is the tight bound of this? or the upper bound? is this n^3? is this n^4? the maximum amount of number i can get out of this? thanks

EDIT: so: for i=1 then: the ans is 1.

i=2: (1*2 + 2*1)
1=3: (1*3 + 2*2 + 3*1)
i=4: (1*4 + 2*3 + 3*2 + 4*1 )

and so on

Comment: homework? probably a question for: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What goes in the `...`?  You are counting up the multiplicand, then suddenly you are counting down.  At what point do you switch?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft - if I got it right, it's a `Sum[i=0..n](N[i] * (N[0] - N[i] + 1))`, where `N[0] = n` and `N[i] = N[i-1] - 1`

Comment: The equation you provided doesn't have any inherent bounds, like an asymptote, or something like that.  Bounds need to be set by the context of the problem.  For example, you may want to do the summation for all values of `n` where `n>=-500` AND `n<=+1000`.

Comment: It's, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {(n-i)^{i+1}}

Comment: no this is not homework came across this when looking at dynamic programming and i was wondering wat would be the upper bound of this expression. i also editted my post to give you examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Wolfram Alpha ...

**Sum[(i + 1) (n - i), {i, 0, n - 1}]**

Comment: i am truly impressed by your answer. this is truly correct , grats

Comment: is: question: is this O(n^3)? or O(n^2)?