# is this expression O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-optimization, polynomial-math

Sum[(i + 1) (n - i), {i, 0, n - 1}]

that is a sum of ( i+1)(n-1) with bounds from i=0 to n-1.

is that O(n^2) or O(n^3)?
and can you explain me how you found it? thanks.

Comment: Your question is inconsistently stated, I think. Is the summand `(i+1)(n-i)` or `(i+1)(n-1)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [i need to find the upper bound of this: or the tight bound:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382014/i-need-to-find-the-upper-bound-of-this-or-the-tight-bound)

Comment: If you weren't satisfied with the answer to i-need-to-find-the-upper-bound-of-this-or-the-tight-bound, you shouldn't have accepted it. Anyway, it's O(n^3).

Comment: by formula calculate O(1) and by use the circle for to write a code that calculate this problem your code is O(n),and if you question   what is the order of resolve sum functions ?,it's O(n^3)...which one is in your mind?

Answer (score 4):

Expand and use the closed-form expressions for sum(i^k). To wit,

```
(i + 1)(n - i) = n * i - i * i + n - i
```

so that

```
sum[(i + 1)(n - i)] = sum(n * i) - sum(i * i) + sum(n) - sum(i)
                    = n * sum(i) - sum(i * i) + n * n - sum(i)
                    = (details elided)
                    = O(n^3).
```

In the step "details elided", expand each sum to its closed-form expression and note that the coefficient of `n^3` is not zero (it's `1 / 6`).

Comment: there's a problem with the reasoning cos the first two terms are nO(n^2) - O(n^3) instead of +.

Comment: @lijie: No. The `n^3` terms don't cancel. We never write `a * O(f(n))` where `a` is a constant and not `1`.

Comment: yes they don't cancel in this case, but if talking about tight bounds (I guess theta is more appropriate), Theta(n^3) - Theta(n^3) may be something other than Theta(n^3). I don't really get the other part (about not writing `a * O(f(n))`). For e.g. n^3 - n^3 = 0, n^3 - (n^3 - n^2) = n^2, etc. So the details of the function are important when performing subtraction

Comment: @lijie: As soon as you write `O(f(n))` you drop the constants. It is not the case that `2 * O(f(n)) - 2 * O(f(n)) = 0` so that signs and constants are irrelevant; (the space of `O(f(n))` over all `f` is not a ring over the real numbers). Thus, you drop them as soon as you pull out `O`.

Comment: @Jason: I am not disputing that (dropping constants). What I disagree with is replacing `-sum(i*i)` with `+ O(n^3)`. If we are talking about O (as in upper bounds), `-sum(i*i)` is `O(1)`, which is `O(n^3)`, admittedly. If we are using O to talk about tight bounds, then there is a problem with computing such bounds using the notation where subtraction occurs.

Comment: @lijie: Please give me a constant `C` and an integer `N` such that for all `n > N` it is true that `|-sum(i * i)| < C * 1`, the sum being taken from `0` to `n - 1`. This is the definition of `O(1)` and you claimed that `-sum(i * i)` is `O(1)` and therefore you should be able to produce for me such constants.

Comment: @Jason, but still, how does one distinguish between a sum like sum(i*i - i*i) from that sum(n*i - i*i) using this method?

Comment: @lijie: Don't pull out asymptotic complexity until you've completely reduced the expression; it is certainly true that `sum(i * i - i * i)` is `O(n^3)` but one can get a better estimate by first simplifying `i * i - i * i` to `0`.

Comment: But that was my issue with the solution you proposed in the first place. Although admittedly my reasoning was flawed. But shouldn't the point be to reduce sum(i) and sum(i^2) to their power sums and perform the subtraction before converting to O()? although for O() it doesn't matter.

Comment: @lijie: Do you see that line that says "details elided"? That's where the details of expanding all the sums to their exact-closed form expressions is performed and one can identify that the coefficient of `n^3` is not zero.

Comment: then the step immediately after (details elided) should just be `= O(n^3)` right? but the actual step placed there seems to imply n*sum(i) is n*O(n^2), and sum(i*i) is O(n^3) and so on. Isn't this a case of not completely reducing the expression?

Comment: @lijie: You're right, I introduced obfuscation by doing it the way I did and what you suggest would be more clear and consistent with what I've been saying. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Jason: Thank you too, for the lesson that asymptotic notation deals with absolutes :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the time needed to evaluate the sum, then it is O(1) (because it can be reduced to a closed-form formula). If you are talking about the formula itself, then expand it and substitute the power sums, and you'll see that the coefficient of n^3 (which is of the highest degree) is not 0.

Anyway, O(n^2) is a subset of O(n^3), so... when asking is it O(n^2) or O(n^3), an easy answer is it is O(n^3) (if you know the answer can never be "neither").

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram|Alpha eats these for lunch:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(i+%2B+1)+(n+-+i),+%7Bi,+0,+n+-+1%7D%5D